# How to print int * & unsigned int* in NSLog?

Tags: objective-c, nslog

How to print `int*` (int pointer) and `unsigned int*` in log using `NSLog`?

```
- (int) doSomethingWith:(unsigned int)Msg withWparam:(unsigned int*)wParam withParameter:(int *) lParam
{
    NSLog(@"MSg:%d wParam:%u lParam:%u",Msg,wParam,lParam);
//not working
    return 1;
}
```

**Warning:** `Format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'unsigned int *'`

Comment: @Downvoter please also tell reason?

Comment: I up voted you since there are stupid trolls on here that down vote when they do not know the answer to something.  But this question did help me out and for that you get my up vote.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `%d` for `int`. And the parameters are pointers, so use `*` to access the values pointed to.

```
NSLog(@"MSg:%d wParam:%u lParam:%d",Msg,*wParam,*lParam);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks @Joris, but its crashing if no value for wParam(means if wParam is nil). How to check that?
// now using:
    NSLog(@"MSG:%d wParam:%u lParam:%d",Msg,*wParam, *lParam);

Comment: You'll have to check for that before logging: `if (!wParam || !lParam) { /* invalid arguments */ }`

Answer (score 14):

`%@` is for objects. `BOOL` is not an object. You should use `%d`.
On the bases of data type `%@` changes as follows

```
For Strings you use %@
For int  you use %i
For float you use %f
For double you use %lf
```

Comment: Then why you use %i for int

Comment: %d, %i   used for Signed Integer and %u for Unsigned Integer